# How to create a user with access to given web shop in Magento 2 multi-store

Tags: magento2, user-roles, user, role

How to make a user in Magento 2 multi-store configuration with giving access him to only 1 sub web shop?

Comment: This functionality available only in EE edition

Answer (score 0):

You can also create custom attribute for customer `store_id` and save there id of store where customer registered.

Then on login, add validation of store_id value and store id that customer want login.